# Mann-Whitney significance and multiple hypothesis testing significance

Tags: multiple-comparisons, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, bonferroni

I am performing various comparisons using the Mann-Whitney U test. Because I'm comparing various groups simultaneously, I am also correcting the p-values for multiple hypothesis testing using Bonferroni correction (global significance considered is $0.05$).

Now, consider for instance that I have some small samples, and all the tests need to be corrected for multiple hypothesis testing. In another post (see: [Significance level as function of sample size in Mann Whitney](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176636/significance-level-as-function-of-sample-size-in-mann-whitney/176651#176651)) one of the answers states that the comparison of samples with sizes $n1=2$ and $n2=3$ detect differences at a $0.05$ significance level. If I was testing 3 different hypotheses, only $p-value < 0.05/3$ would be statistically significant. But this would mean that larger samples would be required, correct? So, instead of sample sizes of $2$ and $3$ to be able to detect any differences at the $0.05$ level, I would instead need $n1=4$ and $n2=3$ or $n1=2$ and $n2=4$?

I am a bit confused about all this... Could someone please help me out understand how to plug in both the sample size and multiple hypothesis testing? Am I thinking correctly?

Answer (score 3):

A sample size of 2 and 3 in the Mann-Whitney has a minimum achievable significance level of 20% two-tailed, not 5%. Did you halve the alpha-level in the table to get a two-tailed alpha instead of doubling?

To have an achievable significance level of 0.05/3 = 1/60   ($\frac13\times\frac{1}{20}=\frac{1}{60}$) two-tailed you'd need to look up a one-tailed in the table of $\alpha=\frac{1}{120}$.

Let's extend the table, but for space reasons I'm dropping the "1/". So here's the reciprocals of the smallest attainable $\alpha$ (we're now looking for values that are at least 120):

```
   m:  2    3    4    5    6    7     8
n                                     
2      6   
3     10   20 
4     15   35   70 
5     21   56  126* 252 
6     28   84  210  462  924 
7     36  120* 330  792 1716 3432 
8     45  165  495 1287 3003 6435 12870
```

The smallest pair of sample sizes that have that small an attainable significance level would be (4,5); alternatively (3,7) also gets there (just), as would (2,14), though that's not in the above table.

If you were doing 6 such comparisons, you'd need a 2-tailed alpha of 0.05/6 $\leq$ 1/120 so you'd in that one-tailed table you'd need $\alpha\leq$ 1/240, or $1/\alpha\geq$ 240 which takes you out to (5,5) or (4,7).

Ten such comparisons pushes you out to (5,6), and so on.

You can always check your calculations by conducting a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test on a pair of non-overlapping samples with the sizes you worked out. For example, in R:

```
> wilcox.test(1:4,5:9)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  1:4 and 5:9
W = 0, p-value = 0.01587
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Note that 0.01587 is 2/126 (rounded off), just under 0.05/3 = 0.01667, so the values of (4,5) we worked out from the table was correct.

---

However if this is anything other than an intellectual exercise ("*Out of curiosity, how low could sample size go?*"), I'd be much more concerned about *power* than achievable significance levels. If you're in planning stages I strongly urge you to consider some power calculation for some meaningful minimum effect size, which will surely increase your required sample sizes above 4-5.

[If you're going to have such tiny sample sizes, why take $\alpha=0.05$ in any case? With such tiny samples your type II error rate may be so high that your type I error rate is almost irrelevant by comparison. There's nothing actually special or useful about 0.05 other than people are used to seeing it; in many cases it's much too high, but if only very small samples are feasible it's quite possibly too low.]

Comment: thanks for all your input! At this moment I cannot answer all your questions, I'll come back to you asap! Thank you very much!
(And indeed, I had probably looked at a one-tailed table :\ )

Comment: The question at the end there is for you to ponder; I don't need an answer to it.